# FOV Vector Direction Matrix

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, matrix, direction

I have a little function which produces the following output. As you can see it's a bit distorted and I'm not that genius in math.

```
private Vector3[] GetFovDirections(int points, float fov) {
    Vector3[] directions = new Vector3[points * points];

    for(int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < points; j++) {
            float angleX = transform.eulerAngles.y - fov / 2 + points * i;
            float angleY = transform.eulerAngles.x - fov / 2 + points * j;

            float x = Mathf.Sin(angleX * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            float y = Mathf.Sin(angleY * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            float z = Mathf.Cos(angleX * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

            directions[i + j * points] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

    return directions;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is desired output?